# How to setText from a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm having problems setting my window's name through a completableFuture.
I need to fetch which account is the user on and with that I'll name the main window.

```
MainWindow mainWindow = this;
...
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        while(true) {
            try {
                // wait until the account is chosen
                if (MainWindow.idAccount > 0 ) {
                    ResultSet rs = // some request to the db
                    rs.next();
                    return rs.getString(1);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error while getting the address of the account. " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).thenAccept(account -> {
        System.out.println(account);
        mainWindow.setText("POS - " + account);
    });
```

Everything works fine, in fact in .thenAccept() the console prints out the correct address of the account. The text, though, is never set.

Could it be something about the access between threads? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `supplyAsync` stage is executing in the common fork-join pool, but updating the UI **must** occur on the UI thread (e.g. _Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)_ in Swing). You should use the `thenAcceptAsync` variant to schedule the stage on the UI thread—see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097911/how-to-settext-from-a-completablefuture#comment102589640_58098235).

Answer (score 0):

I assume MainWindow is a Swing component. And Swing components are updated in EDT.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> mainWindow.setText("POS - " + account));
```

A side note: you can try setting title with `setTitle` if it's a frame.

Comment: In which case one can use `thenAcceptAsync(/*Consumer*/, SwingUtilities::invokeLater)`.

Comment: That’s all assuming the the OP is using AWT or Swing, which was never said anywhere. E.g., the solution for JavaFX would look different.